# Unity Android show Black screen using flutter_unity_widget package

Tags: android, flutter, unity-game-engine

AIM : To load specific element from unity 3D into flutter Android App.

Issue:
I am using flutter_unity_widget in flutter to show unity 3D content. I work fine until i use method like _unityWidgetController.postJsonMessage, It show black screen and content is not accessable.

current code in flutter

```
// Callback that connects the created controller to the unity controller
  void onUnityCreated(controller) {
    _unityWidgetController = controller;
    unity(_unityWidgetController);
  }

 unity(UnityWidgetController _unityWidgetController){
_unityWidgetController.postJsonMessage("Model Selector" , "SelectModel", {"value" : 3});

 _unityWidgetController.postMessage("Model Selector" , "SelectModel", "3");

}
```

flutter_unity_widget: ^2020.3.25

Answer (score 1):

Black screen problem is related with Unity crash. I am working on a Flutter AR App. I am using Flutter + Unity + Vuforia and flutter_unity_widget: ^2022.1.0+2 version. Please try to find your Unity crash. I can share with you my working code example for sending messages from my Flutter App to Unity. I am using it for; when Unity is ready, send this message from Flutter to Unity:

```
void _onUnityCreated(controller) {
    controller.resume();
    _unityWidgetController = controller;
    _unityWidgetController.postMessage("myUnityObject", "myUnityMethod", "myStringParam");
  }
```